# Split audio into many pieces

Tags: windows, linux, audio

I need a tool to split my 45 second audio file on seconds: `3 6 8 12 14 17 20 23 25 27 30 33 36 38 41 43`

Which software should I use (GUI is preferred)? Is there any that is free?

I want to listen to this audio (It is a bunch of words in audio format) and each time the speaker finished saying a word I press, for example, SPACE and the program records that point of time and this process continues until the end of the audio file and finally the program gives me, for example, 20 tiny mp3 files.

Comment: For which operating system? Any special audio formats?

Comment: I have windows but have iso of Ubuntu. So Windows/Unix . mp3 would be better but if it is special I will convert it.

Comment: What do you mean by *it would be better not to specify these by keyboard (I mean giving numbers)*? How are the numbers determined?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend **[Mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/)**. It is free and open source, and available for Windows, Linux or Mac OS X.

It can split MP3, Ogg Vorbis and FLAC files. It does this without decoding, so avoids reducing quality. MP3 is a lossy format, so every time you re-encode a file, you would decrease the quality. Better to losslessly edit the file.

Mp3splt is a command line program, but there is a GUI version, **Mp3splt-gtk**. This allows you to play the file, and add splits at particular points. You can press Alt+A to add a split. Or you can enter the time for each split. It also has silence detection, so can add points based on that. You can also enter names for each part, before splitting into separate files.

[image: mp3splt-gtk]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has plenty of tools for this; many will also run on Windows.

A suitable command line tool is [sox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sox); for manipulating audio with a GUI I always use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).  Both are available for Windows.  Audacity needs a separate plugin to support certain formats, such as MP3.

Comment: I mean I wanna listen to this audio (It is a bunch of words in audio format) and each time the speaker finished saying a word I press for example SPACE from keyboard and the program records that point of time and this process continues until the end of the audio file and finally the program gives me for example 20 tiny mp3 files. I wish I described clearly ....

Comment: Now it is clear, perhaps you can add this to your question?  I like this idea but I don't know any software that supports this directly. `sox` can detect silence so it may be possible to use it to do this automatically.

Comment: @reinierpost Could you please add how this matches the OP's requirements? Pointer: There's a [howto for this job](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/splitting_a_recording_into_separate_tracks.html) directly on the Audacity Wiki (only the asked-for `space` button must be replaced by Ctrl-B). OP could go through the track as described, press Ctrl-B to set markers, and finally use "Export Multiple" to export the clips to separate files.